# prepareForSegue works on iOS7 but not on iOS8

Tags: swift, segue

I've been struggling with this one for a while. The following code runs fine when build for ios7, but when build for ios8 just crashes. Any of these got deprecated on ios8?

Not sure if I am doing wrong by pushing a segue from a `tab bar controller` to a `navigation controller`.

If I comment my `var moveVC` I can transit to the `HobbieFeedViewController`, but then I do not pass any values to the next segue.

If I remove the navigation controller from `HobbieFeedViewController` the segue stops working.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        println("SENDER->\(sender)")
        let cell = sender as! HobbiesTableViewCell
        var cellTitle = String()
        //unwrap safelly
//        if let object = cell.textLabel?.text
        if let object =  cell.cellTitle.text
        {
            cellTitle = object
            println("CELLTITLE->\(cellTitle)")
        }
            // if not
        else
        {
            println("Could not get cellTitle")
        }
        // call segue
        if (segue.identifier == "hobbieFeed")
        {
            var selectedRowIndex = self.myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
//            var moveVC: HobbieFeedViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! HobbieFeedViewController
//            
//            moveVC.moveId = selectedRowIndex!.row
//            moveVC.selectedHobbie = cellTitle

            println("PREPARE ROW->\(selectedRowIndex)")
            println("PREPARE HOBBIE->\(cellTitle)")
        }
    }
```

[image: debug]
[image: view]

Comment: You are casting navigation controller in the view controller, please check your crash log. I have seen in your snapshot.

Comment: remove `HobbieFeedViewController rootView NavigationController` then add a segue

Comment: Ashish, I tried to connect the segue not on the navigation controller, but directly on the view controller. But then it wont call the prepareForSegue methid. Any idea about what I should try?